# PHP PDO like (search)

Tags: php, mysql, search, pdo

I'm using this code to use PDO to generate a search query:

```
                $test = $_POST["user_search"];

                //search for user in database
                $query = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_email LIKE ' . "':search'");
                $keyword = "%".$test."%";
                $query->bindParam(':search', $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query->execute();

                $results = $query->fetchAll();
                print_r($results);

                $query->debugDumpParams()
```

The debug output is:

```
SQL: [50] SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_email LIKE ':search' Params: 1 Key: Name: [7] :search paramno=-1 name=[7] ":search" is_param=1 param_type=2
```

Any idea where things go wrong? For example $_POST["user_search"] was "507" as value. Reading the debug output it seems like there's  a problem because value isn't shown anywhere.

Comment: Try removing the single quotes around :search. PDO doesn't require single quotes as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_email LIKE :search`.  Not sure why you are trying ton concat the query together like that. PDO will replace `:search` with what you pass to it as the value.

Comment: Your acceptance record is quite questionable, in regards to solutions given for past questions.

Answer (score 0):

PDO will put in any quotes necessary to properly escape your data. Placeholders should be put in as-is:

```
$query = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_email LIKE :search');
```

Calling `bindParam` with a string will prompt PDO to use quotes and escape that value accordingly.

Comment: Sorry to see you've fallen onto one with a track record that is quite questionable; first thing I check ;-)

Comment: The `[php]` crowd isn't always the most rewarding, it's true. Too many drive-by questions.

Comment: Got that straight.